# Variable Scope in try-catch block php

Tags: php, scope

I have the following code to determine if a new session should be created based on login information;

```
try {
    $_session = new \Proactivve\User\Sessions($_user);
    $start_session = $_session->startSession();
}
catch (\Proactivve\Exceptions\ProactivveAuthenticationException $e) {
    if($start_session === true) {
        // Successful login
        return array(/* ... */);
    }
    return array(/* ... */);
}
```

wherein I need to check the returned value of `$start_session` from the try block; however, I am getting an `"Undefined variable"` error from PHP (v5.6.11) for the variable. I always thought that variables in PHP were scoped to the file, method or function, not to a block. Why am I receiving this error when the variable should be accessible?

The reason I am checking for a successful login within the `AuthenticationException` exception catcher is that when creating a new instance of the `\Proactivve\User\Sessions` class, I check for an existing session and throw the authentication exception if one is not found, thus I need to check inside of this catch block to determine that the user is not already logged in.

UPDATE:

```
try {
    $_session = new \Proactivve\User\Sessions($_user);
}
catch (\Proactivve\Exceptions\ProactivveAuthenticationException $e) {
    if($_session->startSession() === true) {
        // Successful login
        return array(/* ... */);
    }
    return array(/* ... */);
}
```

This new method understands that after an exception is thrown, PHP stops executing the code in the try block and starts the session in the catch block; however, now I receive `Undefined variable: _session` as the error.

Comment: if you have any exception in `$_session = new \Proactivve\User\Sessions($_user);`  then next line wont execute.. so in cache block change if condition to `if(isset($start_session) && $start_session === true)`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta is it possible to access a variable defined in the try block (namely the `$_session` variable) from the first catch block? I think I will change it to `if($_session->startSession() === true)` if yes

Comment: yes that is also possible.. anothe way is define the variable out side of try block then overwrite in try block and check it in catch block

Comment: I receive the error `Undefined variable: _session` when I run the startSession function in the catch block as `if($_session->startSession() === true)`. Any idea why? $_session should be in the right scope here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `\Proactivve\User\Sessions()` is throwing an exception, then none of the other code in the `try` block is executed. Nothing will be assigned to `$_session`, and the following line is going to be skipped entirely.

Scoping is not your problem, the problem is that the variables are never created. If you need specific values in the `catch` block, you need to create them in a context where they cannot be interrupted by an exception.